# How do I reproduce this pattern when number input is greater than 100?

Tags: java, numbers

I am trying to draw a triangle using a pattern of increasing numbers. Numbers from 1 to 9 looks fine but after 10, it is taking spaces and could not retain a triangle pattern.

**pattern**

```
123456
 12345
  1234
   123
    12
     1
```

[image]

```
    System.out.println("Pattern3: ");//output pattern3
    int input2=input-1;//declare required empty space
    for (int i=0;i<input;i++){ //gen of pattern 
        input2--;//empty space goes down as number increasing
        for (int j=0;j<=input2;j++)//empty space generator
                System.out.print("  ");

           // System.out.println();
        for (int j=i;j>=0;j--)//number linegenerator
            System.out.printf("%s",patternBase[j]);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: edit : find to fine*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this homework?

Comment: my homework is until input 9, my question is legit for me.

Comment: How is it supposed to look like with multi digit numbers? You likely will need to adjust the prints to use the appropriate number of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

It actually is kind of impossible to line up numbers in a triangle pattern above 10 because each number's digits will kind of affect the triangle shape as for numbers greater than 10. Once the digits get greater than 10 they will add 2 digits per number to the pyramid, and when they get to 100 they will start adding 3 digits per number to the new pyramid string, which will completely deform it.

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678910
1234567891011
123456789101112
12345678910111213
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: I know, but it just dosent seem logical that there is an answer for that question. I am also very young for Stack Overflow too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work even for input > 100. Here **java.lang.String#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)** is used to format, but I think it could be done with nested for loops. The basic idea is to calculate **no of digits from 1 to N**, and adjust the no of spaces accordingly.

- For **input 9**, no of digits from 1 to 9 will be 123...9, that is simply 9
- For **input 10**, no of digits from 1 to 10 will be 123...910, that is 9+2(since 10 has two digits 1 and 0)
- For **input 100**, no of digits from 1 to 10 will be 123...910...99100, that is 1*(1-9)+2*(10-99)*3(100-100)

  **Similarly this logic could be extended for any input.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTriangle();
}

private static void printTriangle() {
    int n = 11;
    int noOfDigitsIn1ToN = noOfDigitsIn1ToN(n);

    String format = "%"+noOfDigitsIn1ToN+"s";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String s = "";
        for(int j = 1; j <= n-i; j++) {
            s+=j;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format(format, s));
    }
}

private static int noOfDigitsIn1ToN(int n) {
    int noOfDigitsInN = noOfDigitsInN(n);
    double lowestValueWithNoOfDigitsEquals_noOfDigitsInN = Math.pow(10, noOfDigitsInN - 1);
    double noOfDigitsFrom1ToN = (n - lowestValueWithNoOfDigitsEquals_noOfDigitsInN + 1)*noOfDigitsInN--;
    while (noOfDigitsInN != 0) {
        noOfDigitsFrom1ToN += (Math.pow(10, noOfDigitsInN) - Math.pow(10, noOfDigitsInN - 1))* noOfDigitsInN;
        noOfDigitsInN--;
    }
    Number number = noOfDigitsFrom1ToN;
    return  number.intValue();
}

private static int noOfDigitsInN(int n) {
    int digits = 0;
    int tempn = n;
    while (tempn > 0) {
        digits++;
        tempn /= 10;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

**OutPut**

```
1234567891011
  12345678910
    123456789
     12345678
      1234567
       123456
        12345
         1234
          123
           12
            1
```

Comment: Please eloborate your answer. Code only answers may not help the asker.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich Thanks! I have updated the answer, please check it out.